# How to achieve reliable peer to peer messaging with zeroMQ or some other library out there?

Tags: messaging, zeromq

By reliable I mean

- when subscribers are disconnected we need to be able to send them offline messages.
- there could be any number of subscribers
- Message queue should be persistent in publisher.

So, to deal with that we should have acks from subscribers. We have to have persistent message queue for each subscriber (with what we can do this easy? I heard there is some extensions in postgresql)
The main difficulty for me is how to send messages. Should we use sliding window protocol for that?
That's a lot of work IMHO, so I'm searching some ready solution for that. It couldn't be, that no one is tried to do that before.

Comment: zeromq is not a _ready solution_ for reliable messaging, consider using formal messaging middleware like JMS to address your needs.

Comment: I know that zeromq is not ready solution for reliable messaging.
But that doesn't mean, that there is no external API for that.

Comment: You mean a framework over zeromq that makes it reliable?

Comment: Exactly. But I will look into JMS. I heard about ActiveMQ, but still not figured out how to achieve p2p messaging with persistent queuing.

Comment: @user1685095 what was your final solution to this ?

Comment: @kimathie Well, you can either create your own persistence layer on top on zeroMQ or use messaging systems that already have it. We used rabbitmq.

Answer (score 0):

Persistency requirement implies that the messages must be stored somewhere until consumed. You would normally store messages in a standalone broker, since it allows flexible scaling.

However, if the volume of messages in not too high, they might be stored close to producer. This might be considered to be a broker, embedded into producer. Apache Kafka seems to be a good candidate for this, since it might be easily embedded and perfectly fits your requirements.

Comment: Thank you. I'll read about it.
It's not about volume of messages, it's about reliability. We can't afford start topology, where if one broker would fail, everything else will fail. And also even if it would be a cluster of brokers, what would be if one fail? Will messages that already have been sent  to this broker be lost?

So in my opinion embedded broker is only right solution for that.

Comment: @user1685095: I'd say that embedded broker without replication can't be reliable, since failure of producer machine causes loss of all messages not consumed yet. Separate Kafka broker deployed with replication & failover should be better, if the reliability is primary requirement

Comment: Embedded broker.
In case of hardware failure of producer we would lost only messages, that were not in persistent storage by that time (it wouldn't be many of them).
In case of network failure we wouldn't lost anything.

Separate broker.
In case of hardware failure we again losing all non-persistent messages (not much of them).
In case of network failure between producer and broker wouldn't we lose all messages that producer would produce for the time of network failure?